# Replace urls in code using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to replace urls sitewide: "https://my.oldurl.com/directory" with
new url "https:my.newurl.com"

What am I missing?

Tried:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/https:\/\/my.oldurl.com\/directory\//https:\/\/my.newurl.com//' {} \;
```

returned sed: -e expression #1, char 88:unknown option to `s'

```
sed -i 's#"https://my.oldurl.com/directory"#"https://mt.newurl.com"g'
```

returns sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unterminated `s' command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first command:

```
-type f -exec sed -i 's/https:\/\/my.oldurl.com\/directory\//https:\/\/my.newurl.com//' {} \;
```

Has the wrong number of trailing `/`. Change it to either:

```
-type f -exec sed -i 's/https:\/\/my.oldurl.com\/directory\//https:\/\/my.newurl.com\//' {} \;
```

Or:

```
-type f -exec sed -i 's/https:\/\/my.oldurl.com\/directory\//https:\/\/my.newurl.com/' {} \;
```

Which one depends on whether you want the replacement string to be `https://my.newurl.com` or `https://my.newurl.com/`

Comment: By the way, it could be usefull to add "g" option to the sed (example : `-type f -exec sed -i 's/https:\/\/my.oldurl.com\/directory\//https:\/\/my.newurl.com\//g' {} \;` )
without it `sed` will change only first occurence of oldurl.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with those suggestions. Total newbie. I don't know what "find ./ -type f" is doing exactly. My files on web server are .ctp or .php. When I entered @Smeeheey suggestion it returned a blank prompt. When I entered @Paul Zakharov suggestion it reurned "sed: -e expression #1, char 92: unknown option to `s'"

Comment: If the command succeeded you would expect it to return a blank prompt. The command `sed -i` modifies files in place, using the list given to it by the `find` command (through pipeline). If all is well you see no visible output, but your files will have been edited provided the given string was found. Check your files

Comment: No edits were made. I'm using a tmp directory with a few test files. Perhaps the syntax is incorrect. Am I escaping the slashes correctly in the url?

Comment: In your files does `directory` have a slash on the end? If not, remove the `\/` after `directory` on the command line